# Add haxis line in google bar char

Tags: charts, bar-chart, google-visualization

I need to add horizontal axis line add but default not show.
Any solutions?
Add haxis line in google bar char.

[image]
    ![//days on market
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            [ 'Element','sold quantity', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
            ['Average All Agents',197, '#4DEBEB',197],
            ['Marco Errichiello',109, '#000033',109]
          ]);
          var options = {
            //title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
            width: 600,
            height: 150,
            bar: {groupWidth: '90%'},

```
        //legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'center' },
    legend:{position:'none'},
        hAxis: {
        baselineColor:'#ffffff',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent',
            count:5,
            },
          viewWindow: {
            //max: \[12\],
        min:\[0\],
          },
        },
        vAxis: {
        baselineColor:'#000000',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            },
        textPosition:'none',
        },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('daysonmarket'));
      chart.draw(data, options);][1]
```

If it's possible then please help me!

Answer (score 0):

remove the following option from `hAxis`...

```
color: 'transparent'
```